# How to scrape a webpage which has login if we have the credentials using python scrapy?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Just want to know how to send request along with the login credentials to a login page to fetch the data.

Comment: There is an example in the documentation: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#using-formrequest-from-response-to-simulate-a-user-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usual for web sites to provide pre-populated form fields through  elements, such as session related data or authentication tokens (for login pages). When scraping, you’ll want these fields to be automatically pre-populated and only override a couple of them, such as the user name and password. You can use the FormRequest.from_response() method for this job. Here’s an example spider which uses it:
import scrapy

```
def authentication_failed(response):
    # TODO: Check the contents of the response and return True if it failed
    # or False if it succeeded.
    pass

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example.com'
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        if authentication_failed(response):
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
            return

        # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```